# limit of $f(x) = \lim \limits_{x \to 0} (\frac{\sin x}{x})^{\frac 1x}$

Tags: calculus, limits, functions

Any ideas how to calculate this limit without using taylor?
 $$f(x) = \lim \limits_{x \to 0} \left(\frac{\sin x}{x}\right)^{\frac1x}$$

Comment: Please improve the question by providing additional context, which ideally includes your thoughts on the problem and any attempts you have made to solve it. This information helps others identify where you have difficulties and helps them write answers appropriate to your experience level.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Notice, $$\lim_{x\to 0}\left(\frac{\sin x}{x}\right)^{1/x}$$
$$=\lim_{x\to 0}\exp \left(\frac{1}{x}\ln\left(\frac{\sin x}{x}\right)\right)$$
$$=\lim_{x\to 0}\exp \left(\frac{\ln(\sin x)-\ln(x)}{x}\right)$$
using L'Hosptal's rule for $\frac 00$ form, 
$$=\lim_{x\to 0}\exp \left(\frac{\frac{\cos x}{\sin x}-\frac1x}{1}\right)$$
$$=\lim_{x\to 0}\exp \left(\frac{x\cos x-\sin x}{x\sin x}\right)$$
$$=\lim_{x\to 0}\exp \left(\frac{x(-\sin x)+\cos x-\cos x}{x\cos x+\sin x}\right)$$
$$=\lim_{x\to 0}\exp \left(\frac{-x\sin x}{x\cos x+\sin x}\right)$$
$$=\lim_{x\to 0}\exp \left(\frac{-x\cos x-\sin x}{-x\sin x+\cos x+\cos x}\right)$$
$$=\lim_{x\to 0}\exp \left(\frac{-x\cos x-\sin x}{-x\sin x+2\cos x}\right)$$
$$=\exp \left(\frac{0}{0+2}\right)=e^0=\color{red}{1}$$

Answer (score 5):

Take the log of both sides and examining the 2 sides of the limits yields
$$\ln L^+=\lim \limits_{x \to 0^+} \frac{\ln (\sin x)-\ln(x)}{x}$$
$$\ln L^-=\lim \limits_{x \to 0^-} \frac{\ln (\sin (-x))-\ln(-x)}{x}$$
which can be solved by L'Hopital's to both equal $0$, so the limit is 1.

Comment: This is in fact a little subtler as $x$ can be negative (in which case $\ln x$ and $\ln(\sin x)$ are not defined).

Comment: @W-t-P Which can be remedied by noting that $\ln\left(\frac{\sin x}{x}\right) = \ln\left(\frac{\sin(-x)}{(-x)}\right).$

Comment: @W-t-P, good point.  However, this can be easily fixed since near 0 $sin x$ and $x$ have the same sign, so I will substitute in absolute values to handle the issue.

Comment: Well, with the absolute values you will have a problem differentiating. The right way to handle it is to address separately the left-hand and the right-hand limits (see Cameron Williams' comment).

Comment: @W-t-P I don't think the absolute values will give a problem when differentiating.

Comment: @W-t-P The function $f(x)=\ln|x|$ is differentiable at any $x\ne0$ and $f'(x)=1/x$. The absolute value poses no problem whatsoever.

Comment: @user84413 & egreg: you are right, this is probably more the matter of taste. What is the derivative of $\ln|\sin(x)|$? It is easy to compute but for this we still have to distinguish two cases; that is, essentially, to consider two limits separately.

Comment: @W-t-P Not at all: the chain rule works perfectly and the derivative is $\frac{\cos x}{\sin x}=\cot x$.

Comment: @egreg: Have I claimed there is any problem with it? My claim is that to compute the derivative, you still have to consider separately the two cases $\sin x>0$ and $\sin x<0$ (or use a $\rm{sign}\, x$ which is equivalent to it).

Comment: @W-t-P No, you don't need to separate cases; why would you? If $f(x)=\ln|x|$ and $g(x)=\sin x$, then $f'(x)=1/x$ and so the derivative of $f(g(x))$ is $\frac{g'(x)}{g(x)}=\frac{\cos x}{\sin x}$, by the chain rule.

Comment: @egreg: Yes I do, to compute the derivative of $|x|$.

Comment: @W-t-P You're not reading what I write. Bye.

Comment: @egreg: reciprocated.

Comment: The derivative of $\ln |x|$ is $1/x$ for $x\ne 0$.  Therefore the derivative of $\ln |\sin x|$ is  $(1/\sin x)\cdot \cos x$ for $x$ not a multiple of $\pi.$ Two separate cases not needed.

Answer (score 2):

With Taylor expansions: *(just for reference)*

We will use 
$$\begin{align}
\sin u &= u + o(u^2) \\
\ln(1+x) &= u  + o(u)
\end{align}$$
when $u\to0$. (In particular, $\ln(1+o(u)) = o(u)$.)

---

Write
$$
\left(\frac{\sin x}{x}\right)^{\frac{1}{x}}
= \left(\frac{x+o(x^2)}{x}\right)^{\frac{1}{x}}
= \left(1+o(x)\right)^{\frac{1}{x}}
= e^{ \left(\frac{1}{x}\ln\left(1+o(x)\right)\right) }
= e^{ \left(\frac{1}{x}\left(o(x)\right)\right) }
= e^{o(1) }
$$
so the limit is $e^0=1$.

Comment: The reason I gave up with Taylor is that because I took $ sinu = u+ o(u)$. So you put $o(u^2)$ because of $o(u^2)/x$ ?

Comment: You're not strictly using Taylor series as one could arrive at these results differently too. One should : The question explicitely asked for proofs without taylor expansions

Comment: Because $\sin u = u -\frac{u^3}{6} + o(x^3)$, so in particular there is no $u^2$ term. (Can only see it as $\sin$ is an odd function -- no even order terms.)

Comment: @JohannesHahn My bad -- I didn't see that mention of Taylornessless.

Comment: @ClementC. I didnt get what you meant. why not to use $\sin u = u +o(u)$ ?

Comment: You took Taylor's exapnsion near 0 of order 2. Why of order 1 is not enough?

Comment: @SijaanHallak Because then the bound is too weak: you will only get $(1+o(1))^{1/x}$, which is $$e^{\frac{1}{x}\ln(1+o(1))}  = e^{o\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)}.$$ This is not enough to conclude. (as $o\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)$ does not imply convergence to $0$: e.g., $\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}} = o\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)$.)

Answer (score 2):

HINT.-$$ (\frac{\sin x}{x})^{1/x}=\left([1+(\frac{\sin x}{x}-1)]^{\frac{1}{\frac{\sin x}{x}-1)}}\right)^{\frac{\sin x-x}{x^2}}$$

It follows $$\lim \limits_{x \to 0} (\frac{\sin x}{x})^{1/x}=e^{\lim {x\to 0}\frac{\sin x -x}{x^2}}=e^0=1$$

Comment: But how do you justify that last limit?

Comment: I saw it as immediate, developping $\sin x$ till the second term.

Comment: Fair enough -- I was wondering whether this step was Taylor-free :)

Answer (score 1):

Here's a proof
that just uses
basic properties
of
$\sin, \cos$,
and
$\ln$.

Since
$-1 \le \cos(x) < 1$
and $\sin'(x) = \cos(x)$
and $\cos'(x) = -\sin(x)$,
$\sin(x)
=-\int_0^x \cos(t) dt
$
so
$|\sin(x)|
\le |x|
$.

Also,
since,
for $x > 0$,
$\ln(1+x)
=\int_1^{1+x} \frac{dt}{t}
=\int_0^{x} \frac{dt}{1+t}
$,
$\ln(1+x)
\le x
$
and,
for $1 > x > 0$,
$\ln(1-x)
=\int_1^{1-x} \frac{dt}{t}
=-\int^1_{1-x} \frac{dt}{t}
=-\int^0_{-x} \frac{dt}{1+t}
$,
so,
if $\frac12 > x > 0$,
$-\ln(1-x)
=\int^0_{-x} \frac{dt}{1+t}
\ge \frac{x}{1-x}
\ge 2x
$.
Therefore,
for
$-\frac12 < x < 1$,
$|\ln(1+x)|
\le 2|x|
$.

$\begin{array}\\
\cos(x)
&=1-2\sin^2(x/2)\\
&=1+O(x^2)
\qquad\text{with the implied constant
being less than 1},\\
\text{so that}\\
\frac{\sin x}{x}
&=\frac1{x}\int_0^x \cos(t)dt\\
&=\frac1{x}\int_0^x (1+O(t^2))dt\\
&=\frac1{x} (t+O(t^3))|_0^x\\
&=\frac1{x} (x+O(x^3))\\
&=1+O(x^2))\\
\text{so}\\
\ln(\frac{\sin x}{x})
&=\ln(1+O(x^2))\\
&=O(x^2)\\
\text{so}\\
\frac1{x}\ln(\frac{\sin x}{x})
&=\frac1{x}(O(x^2))\\
&=O(x)\\
&\to 0 \text{ as }x \to 0\\
\text{so}\\
(\frac{\sin x}{x})^{1/x}
&\to 1\\
\end{array}
$